# How to tell if the whole file has been downloaded using stream_copy_to_stream?

Tags: php, sockets

http://php.net/stream_copy_to_stream `$maxlength` parameter allows to limit the number of bytes to copy.

How to tell if the limit was breached, ie. not the whole file was downloaded?

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 0):

With regards to Yousuf Memon comment (http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), my approach to the issue is simple logic:

```
public function download($size_limit)
{
    if($this->temp_file)
    {
        throw new UploadRemoteImageException('Resource has been downloaded already.');
    }

    $this->temp_file    = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), $this->temp_file_prefix);

    $src    = fopen($this->url, 'r');
    $dest   = fopen($this->temp_file, 'w+');

    stream_copy_to_stream($src, $dest, $size_limit+1000);

    if(filesize($dest) > $size_limit)
    {
        // The file size limit has been breached.
    }

    // [..]
}
```

This works by simply adding more bytes on top of the user defined limit. Then when the stream is closed, it check if the file is larger than the user defined size limit (, which can be because we added the 1000 bytes on top).

However, I can't tell with confidence if this will always work, as I assume it also depends on the chunk size.